# Spyne: Integer Validation how can I set minimum digit limit?

Tags: spyne

I want to add validation for an Integer, that its minimum digit value is **5** and maximum digit value is **20**

For Integer I have set following validations

```
Integer(min_occurs=1, gt=9999, max_str_len=20, nillable=False)
```

I just put work around for **min_str_len**, I do not find any attribute for **min_str_len**.
Instead of work around is there any default way ?

Comment: It seems you used `gt` to limit minmum allowed value. Are there any disadvantages of that solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `Integer` type (or another one that fits best) and implement `validate_native` method.

Example for prime number check from docs:

```
from math import sqrt, floor

class Prime(UnsignedInteger):
    """Custom integer type that only accepts primes."""

    @staticmethod
    def validate_native(cls, value):
        return (
            UnsignedInteger.validate_native(value) and \
            all(a % i for i in xrange(2, floor(sqrt(a))))
        )
```

Source: http://spyne.io/docs/2.10/manual/05-02_validation.html#a-native-validation-example